# react swiper - Cannot convert undefined or null to object when using Thumbs module on nextjs modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

while creating swiper thumbs component in next.js 14 `Cannot convert undefined or null to object when using Thumbs module` this component is thrown this error
swiper v11.0.5

tries this the workaround is
`thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper }}`
replace to
`thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper && !thumbsSwiper.destroyed ? thumbsSwiper : null }}` didnt work still issue is present.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
// Import Swiper styles
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/free-mode";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/thumbs";

import "./styles.css";

// import required modules          
import { Navigation, Thumbs, A11y, Scrollbar } from "swiper/modules";

export default function SwiperComp() {
  const [thumbsSwiper, setThumbsSwiper] = useState();
const swiperRef =useRef(null)
  return (
    <>
<ModalWrapper>
      <Swiper
       
        thumbs={thumbsSwiper ? { swiper: thumbsSwiper } : undefined}
        modules={[Navigation, Thumbs, A11y, Scrollbar]}


      >
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
  <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
        
      </Swiper>
      <Swiper
        onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper}
        spaceBetween={10}
        slidesPerView={10}
        watchSlidesProgress={true}
        modules={[Navigation, Thumbs, A11y]}
      >
        

        <SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
<SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
<SwiperSlide>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
        </SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
    </>
</ModalWrapper>
  );
}
```